# TI TMS320C64xx : add a PRD function

Tags: signal-processing, ti-dsp

I have to add a function that will run every specified period. it seems straight forward as Code composer has a GUI tool to do that : DSP/BIOS Condig->PRD->

[alt text http://bauhaus.ece.curtin.edu.au/~iain/c54-tutorial/images/Image33.gif](http://bauhaus.ece.curtin.edu.au/~iain/c54-tutorial/images/Image33.gif)

in the properties form I can fill in the  function name that gets called with every clk interrupt, but the GUI rejects my functions  as "undefined labels'

the function I want to call is a C++ static function  :  `static void  MyClass::func1()`

what am i missing here ?

Comment: Just a guess, but you might need to define the function to be called as `extern "C"`, to avoid the name mangling. The GUI tool might only look for unmangled C-style names.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to have it be an extern "C" function.